# Updating and not replacing wordpress custom fields with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax, wordpress

I need updating a custom field in wordpress. I have several images in a gallery with a textarea for comments attached to every single image. Now I'm able to write text in a textarea of an image and the text is saved with ajax instatly after typing in the db. That works. However when adding text to yet another the first text dissapears again. How can I add a second comment without deleting the others?

The entries in the db looks like when adding a comment to the first picture:

> a:1:{i:8978;s:20:"Picture Comment no 1";}

When adding a comment to another one the whole entry looks like this:

> a:1:{i:8977;s:19:"Picture Comment no2";}

So it overwrites the first one

It needs to look like this:

> a:2:{i:8978;s:19:"Picture Comment no1";i:8977;s:19:"Picture Comment
>   no2";}

That's the mySQL db
[image]

And my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['method']) && $_POST['method'] == 'comment')
{
    //Get current commentd images
    $current_images_comment = get_post_meta('9550', 'gallery_images_comment', true);

    if(!empty($current_images_comment))
    {
        if ( !in_array( $image_id, $current_images_comment ) ) {
            $current_images_comment[] = $image_id;
        }

       $current_images_comment = array_unique($current_images_comment);

       $poddata = Array( $image_id =>$comm_text );
       update_post_meta('9550', 'gallery_images_comment', $poddata);


    }

}
```

comm_text contains the text from textarea

```
if(isset($_POST['comm_text']))
{
    $comm_text = $_POST['comm_text'];
}
```

Comment: I added where $comm_text is set. However this variable contains just the text e.g "Picture Comment no2"

Comment: ah ok, yes that's the problem that it replaces the value of gallery_images_comment.  How can I solve this and add the new value instead of replacing it? I saw this in another theme's function and they did it with update by first reading all gallery_images_comment and then appending the new value

Comment: can you help me and tell me how to do that?   $current_images_comment  contains the previous comments

Comment: Aha, so I should pay you now on this plattform that you give me a hint for a function I could use?

Comment: Ok, we wait for someone helpful

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I solved the question with this little code appending new values to the existing array

```
$poddata = $current_images_comment;
$poddata[$image_id] = $comm_text;
```

Maybe it's useful for someone else, too

```
if(isset($_POST['method']) && $_POST['method'] == 'comment')
        {
            //Get current commentd images
            $current_images_comment = get_post_meta($gallery_id, 'gallery_images_comment', true);

            if(!empty($current_images_comment))
            {

      $poddata = $current_images_comment;
      $poddata[$image_id] = $comm_text;
            } else {
/*if no entry in db*/
  $poddata = Array(
      $image_id =>$comm_text
      );

}

  update_post_meta($gallery_id, 'gallery_images_comment', $poddata);
        }
```